# How to run a child event only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do mouseleave only once after focus triggered. How?
I try several options like off,preventDefault,stopPropagation, return false; but none have worked.

Thank you in advance.

```
addEvent(date, 'focus', function () {
    console.log("focuz" + this.innerHTML);
    document.designMode = 'on';

    addEvent(swap_date, 'mouseleave', function (e) {
        console.log("mouseleave" + this.innerHTML);
        //document.designMode = 'on';
        $(this).off(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: Do you know about [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)?

Answer (score 0):

fixed in mouseenter event to trigger the check with stop var.
Once mouseleave happends, the stop is on.

```
addEvent(swap_date, 'mouseenter', function () {
stop = false;
});

addEvent(swap_date, 'focus', function () {
document.designMode = 'on';

if (this.innerHTML != "") {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.swapDate').bind('mouseleave', function (event) {
            if (!stop && this.innerHTML != "")
            checkDate(this.innerHTML);
            stop = true;
            $('.swapDate').unbind('mouseleave');
        });


    });
}
});
```